# Why inputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter classes hasbeen designed in java?

Tags: inputstreamreader

i studied inputStreamReader used to convert bytes to Character and OutputStreamWriter for Charcter to Byte. But what does it actually mean here by this i.e **Charcter to Byte** conversion and **byte to charcter** conversion. What actually happens internally .Everything is stored as bytes in our system . can't we use simply byte stream classes for reading and writing data of any type. Please help me to make this concept clear.

Comment: Here's a byte: 42. What character does it represent? How would you know if I didn't tell you? Here's a character: ß. What bytes do we use to store that? Again, how would you know? What (sequence of) numbers represent what characters is called an encoding. There are lots of them, so you need a translator. Enter `InputStreamReader`/`OutputStreamWriter`.

Comment: @Jeroen Thank You very much for quick answer..

Comment: why  we need translator (like InputStreamReader )for reading character type data .Character is also stored as bytes(i.e in form of 0 and 1) in system like other types of data . If we need a translator for conversion of bytes, then what is responsible for translating in case of FileInputStream class. what is the internal mechanism when FileInputStream read character. How FileInputStream class is able to read character from text file?

Comment: Internally, Java stores all strings as encoded in UTF-16. So if your characters happen to be encoded in UTF-16, you *could* read the bytes directly. But most text is not stored as UTF-16, but as (say) ASCII or UTF-8. If you simply read those bytes and treated them as characters, you'd end up with garbage. If there was no `OutputStreamWriter`, you would never be able to write characters in a different encoding.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the reply..i have one confusion in the above comment..When we write data to file ,then by default it write to the platform default character encoding (i.e the encoding used by OS on which jvm is installed)unless we specify it or it always store as UTF-16. Please correct me if i am wrong.Thanks..

Comment: According to the documentation, if you don't specify an encoding, the "default" encoding for the platform is used (as in, the platform Java is running on, not the JVM itself). This is almost certainly not UTF-16, and in fact because you don't know what it is it's probably a bad idea to rely on it, unless you know the file will never leave the machine it's stored on. For interchangeability, UTF-8 is generally a good choice because it's compatible with ASCII and can still store all of Unicode.